# Различие  в  значении  слов

Tags: фразеология

Имеется  ли  различие в  словах  "педагог"  и  "преподаватель"  по  их  значению?

Answer (score 2):

По Ожегову педагог - лицо, занимающееся преподавательской и воспитательной работой.Произошло от(гр. paidagogos pals (paidos) дитя + ago веду, воспитываю).
Когда-то это был раб,ведущий ребёнка в школу, присматривающий за ним.

Есть специальности: педагог профессионального обучения, социальный педагог, сурдопедагог,педагог-преподаватель развивающих занятий в дошкольных заведениях.

А есть преподаватель педагогики - науки о преподавании, т.е.обучении и воспитании.

Преподаватель(по Ожегову) - работник средней или высшей школы,преподающий какой-либо предмет, урокодатель. Понятие более узкое, чем педагог.

Много говорят о педагогическом мастерстве преподавателя, заключающемся в  высоком уровне подачи знаний, навыков, умений, в умении научить учиться, воспитании нравственно высоких свойств личности ученика, организаторских способностях, психологической готовности и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Имеется. Главное, думается, то, что педагог занимается только с детьми в школе, иногда - в детском саду, а преподаватель - может и взрослым преподавать, на курсах, например. 
С другой стороны, педагог может и не быть преподавателем. Педагог-воспитатель.